# Instagram Uploading Progress View?

Tags: ios, image-uploading, instagram

I want to make a progress indicator like Instagram.

[image: Instagram Uploading Screenshot]

Do you know how to make one, or any iOS Control already done it?

Comment: I made it myself. If anyone else is needed, let me know.

Comment: can you share it git hub

Comment: can you share it @KONG